# Javascript - prevent onclick event from being attached to all elements with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a simple form that includes an input field where the user will fill in the required amount by clicking the incrementor/decrementor. The form is created based on data pulled dynamically from the database

Below is the problematic part: html and the jquery handling it:

The incrementor, decrementor and the input field:

```
<a href="#" class="removeItem" style = "color: tomato;">-</a>
<input type="text" id="purchase_quantity" class = "purchase_quantity" min="1" max="6" delta="0"  style = "width: 32px;" value="1">
<a href="#" class="addItem" style = "color: tomato;">+</a>
```

and the jquery handling the above:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.addItem').on('click', function () {
        var inputval = $(this).siblings('.purchase_quantity').val();
        var num = +inputval;
        num++;

        if(num>6)num=6;
            console.log(num);
            $(".purchase_quantity").val(num); 
        return false;
    });

    $('.removeItem').on('click', function () {
        var inputval = $(this).siblings('.purchase_quantity').val();
        var num = +inputval;
        num--;

        if(num<1)num=1;
            console.log(num);
            $(".purchase_quantity").val(num); 
        return false;
    });
});
```

Now, what's happening is: onclick of the incrementor/decrementor (+ and -) the value on the input field changes across all the fields in the page instead of the one clicked only. Have spent quite some time on this with no success and will appreciate some help

Comment: Because you are changing them all, of course it happens. Strange that you use correct input here `$(this).siblings('.purchase_quantity')` but don't when you update fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
$(".purchase_quantity").val(num);
```

says, literally, to change the value on all the fields.  Earlier you used

```
$(this).siblings('.purchase_quantity').val()
```

to get the value, so why not also use

```
$(this).siblings('.purchase_quantity').val(num)
```

to set it?

Comment: unsure of how i missed it. will accept your answer shortly..thanks

Comment: By the way, since I only see the fragment of HTML I don't know, but smoksnes may also have a point depending on how those input fragments fit into the broader page.  And while Crabime is wrong, his suggestion does point to a possible error: if you have multiple elements with the same ID (that is, if many inputs look like `<input type="text" id="purchase_quantity" class = "purchase_quantity" min="1" max="6" delta="0"  style = "width: 32px;" value="1">`) this is an error since `id` must be unique

Comment: noted. that's why i'm using class to capture the values

Answer (score 2):

That's because [`siblings`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) will get you all items on the same level.

> Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements,
>   optionally filtered by a selector.

Place them in separate `div` elements, and adjust your setter to actually only update the siblings inside that `div`.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.addItem').on('click', function () {
        var inputval = $(this).siblings('.purchase_quantity').val();
        var num = +inputval;
        num++;

        if(num>6)num=6;
            console.log(num);
            $(this).siblings('.purchase_quantity').val(num); 
        return false;
    });

    $('.removeItem').on('click', function () {
        var inputval = $(this).siblings('.purchase_quantity').val();
        var num = +inputval;
        num--;

        if(num<1)num=1;
            console.log(num);
            $(this).siblings('.purchase_quantity').val(num); 
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <a href="#" class="removeItem" style = "color: tomato;">-</a>
    <input type="text" id="purchase_quantity2" class = "purchase_quantity" min="1" max="6" delta="0"  style = "width: 32px;" value="1">
    <a href="#" class="addItem" style = "color: tomato;">+</a>
</div>

<div>
    <a href="#" class="removeItem" style = "color: tomato;">-</a>
    <input type="text" id="purchase_quantity1" class = "purchase_quantity" min="1" max="6" delta="0"  style = "width: 32px;" value="1">
    <a href="#" class="addItem" style = "color: tomato;">+</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you should change `$(".purchase_quantity").val(num)` to `$("#purchase_quantity").val(num)`